# Import bitbucket into PHPStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

I feel like I have tried Everything but I keep getting a clone fail error:

Here is what I did

```
Open PHPStorm ->VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git
```

In Git Repository URL: I insert `https://MrRasmussen@bitbucket.org/MrRasmussen/udlejnings-priser.git`

Parent Directory: `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Directory name: `udlejnings-priser`

Now when I press Test I get the following error:

```
Repository test has failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have any `@` symbols. You need to get a url that does not have this. For example, if you try to clone from this URL:

```
https://github.com/gamesbrainiac/requests.git
```

It will work fine.

Comment: how will i do this when i use bitbucket?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Also, use SSH option not HTTPS.

Comment: Why is this marked as correct if it doesn't contain the answer for bitbucket?

Comment: Replace `https://user@bitbucket.org/[user]/[repository].git` with `https://bitbucket.org/[user]/[repository].git` and it will work like `GitHub`.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend you to download a bitbucket plugin for PHPStorm.
File > Settings > [Search for] plugins > Browse repositories > [Search for] Bitbucket

It will help you to clone your projects.

Comment: Do not add "Bitbucket" plugin searching through repositories in phpstorm,(NOT working anymore), instead download the zip file from [https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads](https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads)

Comment: Could you please update this answer by recommending a 2022 year plugin?

Comment: @Pathros unfortunately, I can't find any plugin that specifically handles cloning repositories, at least not a major plugin used by lots of people. What is your issue, still the same as the OP?

Answer (score 6):

An alternate bitbucket plugin released by atlassian - works better than the jetbrains plugin for me.
https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads

- Download and extract the most recent zip file - ex: jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-139.224.zip
- Select Install from disk option and point to the bitbucket.jar file within the folder you just extracted

Comment: This is the only solution that really works.. Do not add "Bitbucket" plugin searching through repositories in phpstorm, instead download the zip file from bitbucket from provided link in this answer.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you please update this answer by recommending a 2022 year plugin?

Answer (score 5):

The BitBucket plugin does not work with the latest version of Phpstorm (8.0.3 build 139.1348)

Games Brainiac's answer, although not addressing BitBucket directly does help solving the issue. Taking the @ from the url forces to also get rid of the username, so, the url becomes https://bitbucket.org/[user]/[repository].git

This brings up the authentication window in Phpstorm and starts cloning the repo.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! For future readers: note that copying the HTTPS URL from bitbucket.org didn't work, this method did.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (just remove `user@` from the default link provided by bitbucket). *Phpstorm 2018.3.4*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, since an answer was given. 
At this point (PHPStorm version 10.0.3) but earlier on also: You **can** use an @ in the repository link.

You do need to download and install Git on your windows machine. See the link here:
https://git-scm.com/downloads/

Then you need to go to add the git.exe path to the git executible path in the plugin settings. Go to File -> Settings (or press CTRL + ALT + S)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this solution worked for me. I also tried cloning directly from the welcome screen. However, no luck.

What I did was I opened an existing project, clicked on `VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git` and entered all the details there. When I tested it, it asked for a password for my BitBucket account and it worked.

Comment: install git first

Answer (score 0):

When using Bitbucket to clone into your localhost and IDE, you have several options:

- clone via SSH
- clone via HTTPS

When using HTTPS, the problem is that Bitbucket's default URL format is

```
https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```

Many programs do not like this (special @ character in URL), not just PhpStorm.
Another problem is that Bitbucket now only returns a generic 403 error even when you're able to connect but something goes wrong.

So the recommended options are:

- connect manually by later editing the ./git/config file or via command line
- connect using the JetBrains Bitbucket connector plugin

Remember that in both cases **you must specify repo URL including your password** such as:

```
https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```

If you use the default Bitbucket URL, it will work in some other IDEs (such as Netbeans) but not in PhpStorm.

Also when using the connector plugin, by default you'll be able to use only one Bitbucket  account. To use a different one, again, you need to edit the repo URL manually.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers might have worked at the time. But after losing two hours trying to make this work on phpstorm. Just make sure you have SourceTree installed. and a normal clone from vcs works